# Where were the Omaze walk-ons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Prior to the release of Star Trek Beyond, the cast [promoted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-COeaGn5x0) an Omaze philanthropic sweepstakes for to win a walk-on role in the new movie. They [announced](http://blog.omaze.com/star-trek-to-boldly-go-winner-recap/) the winners, but do we know where they were in the fim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was only one walk-on grand prize, that won by **[Adam Horwitz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YZmQ6uEf88)**.

[image]

To quote from the [Star Trek Magazine: Beyond the Movie Special](http://titanmagazines.com/t/souvenir-one-shots/us/star-trek-beyond/movie-special/)

> We had a lot of fun watching Adam **run around set in his specially made
>   Starfleet uniform,** and it was a blast watching him on camera. He was
>   a total natural! The whole crew was cheering him on the entire way.

and from the "[Going ‘Beyond’ at the Star Trek Experience](http://blog.omaze.com/chaperoning-the-star-trek-experience/)" feature on the Omaze Blog

> Our grand prize winner won a walk-on role, so we got to watch him
>   shoot a scene! We were all situated in a special Omaze tent that had a
>   bunch of chairs, headphones and two monitors, so we could sit and
>   watch Adam’s claim to fame. **He was clearly visible in the background
>   of the scene, and when he wrapped,** the entire cast and crew clapped
>   for him. Yay, Adam!

---

For the record, I've not been able to find any specific confirmation which scene he was in.

Comment: Based on the comments on the Omaze article, I'm guessing he was in a crowd scene, one without any of the main actors, possibly a scene on the Yorktown or in the prison camp.